# SwiftUI change filter and update view

Tags: swift, dynamic, filter, swiftui

The problem is the following, I have an **array of products**, the products have a field called **productCategory**, I have to update the view based on the filter applied.
The Good: the good part is that I can change the filter using binding and when this happens the products disappear.
The Problem: I don't know how to call the products to be displayed again.

Where the products are added to view:

```
struct ProductsList: View {
    var products = productsData
    var categories = categoryData
    @State var selectedCategory : String = ""
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(categories){ item in
                    //create the filter buttons
                    CategoryView(name : item.name, selectedCategory: self.$selectedCategory)
                }
            }
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack{ // add the products to the view
                             if self.selectedCategory == item.productCategory {
                                ProductView(image: item.image, title: item.title, 
                                restaurant: item.restaurant, expensive: item.expensive,
                                productCategory: item.productCategory, restaurantCategory:
                                item.restaurantCategory, price: item.price,
                                weight: item.weight)
                        }
```

Where the filter is updated:

```
struct CategoryView: View {
    var name = ""
    @Binding var selectedCategory : String //filter that is binded to the view
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                print("Button pressed")
                print(self.name)
                if self.selectedCategory != self.name { //change filter based on the button pressed
                    self.selectedCategory = ""
                    self.selectedCategory = self.name

                }
            }) {
                Text(name)
                    .font(.custom("Inter-Medium", size: 16))
                    .foregroundColor(Color("ProductSubtitle"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to recall the ForEach for displaying the new products?? In the image atached are the filter buttons and the category of the product. Please I am stuck...

[image]

Complete code is below:

```
struct ProductsList: View {
   var products = productsData
   var categories = categoryData
   @State var selectedCategory : String = ""
   var body: some View {

       VStack {
           HStack {
               ForEach(categories){ item in
                   //create the filter buttons
                   CategoryView(name : item.name, selectedCategory: self.$selectedCategory)
               }
           }
           ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {


               HStack{
                   //add products to the view
                   ForEach(products) { item in
                       if self.selectedCategory == "" {
                           ProductView(image: item.image, title: item.title, restaurant: item.restaurant, expensive: item.expensive, productCategory: item.productCategory, restaurantCategory: item.restaurantCategory, price: item.price,
                                       weight: item.weight)
                       }
                       else
                           if self.selectedCategory == item.productCategory {
                               ProductView(image: item.image, title: item.title, restaurant: item.restaurant, expensive: item.expensive, productCategory: item.productCategory, restaurantCategory: item.restaurantCategory, price: item.price,
                                           weight: item.weight)
                       }

                   }
                       //                    .frame(width: 210, height: 317)
                       .padding(.horizontal, 25)
               }



           }

       }
   }
}

struct ProductsList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
       ProductsList()
   }
}
```

```
struct products: Identifiable {
   var id = UUID()
   var image: String
   var title: String
   var restaurant: String
   var expensive: String
   var productCategory: String
   var restaurantCategory: String
   var price : String
   var weight : String
}


struct category: Identifiable {
   var id = UUID()
   var name: String
}



let categoryData = [
   category(name : "Burgers"),
   category(name : "Vegan"),
   category(name : "European"),
   category(name : "Pizza")
]


let productsData = [
   products(image: "Product1", title: "Spicy Chicken Burger", restaurant: "Lombardo's Bistro", expensive: "$$", productCategory: "Burger", restaurantCategory: "Fast Food", price: "8.99", weight: "415"),
   products(image: "Product2", title: "Big Tasty", restaurant: "Mc Donald's", expensive: "$$", productCategory: "Burger", restaurantCategory: "Fast Food", price: "11.99", weight: "355"),
   products(image: "Product1", title: "Pizza Diavola", restaurant: "Pizza Giovana", expensive: "$$", productCategory: "Pizza", restaurantCategory: "Italian", price: "13.99", weight: "515"),
   products(image: "Product2", title: "Crispy Strips", restaurant: "KFC", expensive: "$", productCategory: "Chicken", restaurantCategory: "Fast Food", price: "8.99", weight: "415")
]
```

```
struct ProductView: View {
   var image = "Image"
   var title = "Big Mc"
   var restaurant = "Mc Donald's"
   var expensive = "$"
   var productCategory = "Burger"
   var restaurantCategory = "Fast Food"
   var price = "8.99"
   var weight = "410"
   var body: some View {
       VStack(alignment: .leading){
           Image(image)
               .renderingMode(.original)
               .resizable()
               .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
               .frame(width: 175, height: 160)
               .padding(.bottom, 8)
               .padding(.top, 10)

           Text(title)
               .font(.custom("Inter-SemiBold", size: 16))
               .foregroundColor(Color("ProductTitle"))
               .multilineTextAlignment(.center)

           Text(restaurant)
               .font(.custom("Inter-Regular", size: 12))
               .foregroundColor(Color("ProductSubtitle"))
               .padding(.bottom, 10)

           HStack {
               Text(expensive)

               Text("•" + productCategory)

               Text("•" + restaurantCategory)
           }
           .font(.custom("Inter-Regular", size: 8))
           .foregroundColor(Color("ProductSubtitle"))

           HStack(spacing: 2) {
               Text(price)
                   .font(.custom("Inter-SemiBold", size: 16))
                   .foregroundColor(Color("ProductTitle"))
               Text("/")
                   .font(.body)
                   .foregroundColor(.gray)
               Text(weight)
                   .font(.custom("Inter-Regular", size: 12))
                   .foregroundColor(Color("ProductSubtitle"))

               Spacer()

               Button(action: {}) {
                   Image(systemName: "plus")
                       .foregroundColor(Color(.white))

               }
               .padding(.horizontal, 12)
               .padding(.vertical, 12)
               .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
               .background(Color(red: 0.843, green: 0.1, blue: 0.124))
               .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous))

           }
           .padding(.trailing , 15)
       }
       .background(Color(hue: 1.0, saturation: 0.0, brightness: 1.0))
   }
}


struct CategoryView: View {
   var name = ""
   @Binding var selectedCategory : String //filter that is binded to the view
   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           Button(action: {
               print("Button pressed")
               print(self.name)
               if self.selectedCategory != self.name {
                   self.selectedCategory = ""
                   self.selectedCategory = self.name

               }
           }) {
               Text(name)
                   .font(.custom("Inter-Medium", size: 16))
                   .foregroundColor(Color("ProductSubtitle"))
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Link to GitHub:
https://github.com/Bogdan-Blaj/FilterButtons

Comment: it would be a great help, if you can copy here a reproducable runnable example of your problem, so we can check it out instead of guessing what your code does....

Comment: Added all the code for the component and link to GitHub for easier access to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that your filter name did not match with your categoryname.

if you replace your code with my code, you can tap on "all" to see all and on "Burgers" to see Burgers.

the other problem was that you didn't have a button/category to "reset" your category, so i added "all" for this.

```
struct CategoryView: View {
    var name = ""
    @Binding var selectedCategory : String //filter that is binded to the view
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                print("Button pressed")
                print(self.name)

                if self.selectedCategory != self.name {
                    self.selectedCategory = self.name

                }
                if self.selectedCategory == "Burgers" {
                    self.selectedCategory = "Burger"
                }

                if self.selectedCategory == "All" {
                    self.selectedCategory = ""
                }
            }) {
                Text(name)
                    .font(.custom("Inter-Medium", size: 16))
                    .foregroundColor(Color("ProductSubtitle"))
            }
        }
    }
}

let categoryData = [
    category(name : "All"),
    category(name : "Burgers"),
    category(name : "Vegan"),
    category(name : "European"),
    category(name : "Pizza")
]
```

and replace this (i know it looks ridiculous, but else, if you press vegan(which would be an empty list and press then all again, nothing happens)

```
HStack{
                    //add products to the view
                    ForEach(products) { item in
                        if self.selectedCategory == "" {
                            ProductView(image: item.image, title: item.title, restaurant: item.restaurant, expensive: item.expensive, productCategory: item.productCategory, restaurantCategory: item.restaurantCategory, price: item.price,
                                        weight: item.weight)
                        }
                        else
                            if self.selectedCategory == item.productCategory {
                                ProductView(image: item.image, title: item.title, restaurant: item.restaurant, expensive: item.expensive, productCategory: item.productCategory, restaurantCategory: item.restaurantCategory, price: item.price,
                                            weight: item.weight)
                            } else {
                                Text("")
                            }

                        }
                        //                    .frame(width: 210, height: 317)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 25)
```

Comment: I like your answer, thank you for the response! The idea of an reset button was nice, the only improvement, thank you!